# Function overloading problems in inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, overloading

When I am learning function overloading, I know that a function differs from another by its name and number of parameters. So I try similar things for inheritance.

I declare a function without parameters in base class, and declare another function with **the same name but different number of parameters in derived class**.

From my function overloading and inheritance knowledge, the main code should work, but it turns out that the function in the base class is not inherited and I have to explicitly call it.

Could anyone explain to me about this behavior? Shouldn't breathe() be inherited by the derived class? Thanks a lot.

```html
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

//base class
class animal {
 public:
  void breathe(){
   cout << "animal breathe" << endl;
  }
};

//derived class
class fish: public animal {
 public:
  void breathe(int a){
   cout << "fish bubble" << endl;
  }
};

int main() {
 fish fh;

 // correct
 fh.breathe(1);
 // correct
 fh.animal::breathe();
 // error
 fh.breathe();
 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

n3376 10.2/3-4-5

> The lookup set for f in C, called S(f, C), consists of two component
>   sets: the declaration set, a set of members named f; and the subobject
>   set, a set of subobjects where declarations of these members (possibly
>   including using-declarations) were found. **In the declaration set,
>   using-declarations are replaced by the members they designate,** and
>   type declarations (including injected-class-names) are replaced by the
>   types they designate. S(f, C) is calculated as follows:
>
> **> If C contains a declaration of the name f, the declaration set
>   contains every declaration of f declared in C that satisfies the
>   requirements of the language construct in which the lookup occurs. If
>   the resulting declaration set is not empty, the subobject set contains
>   C itself, and calculation is complete.**
>
> **> Otherwise (i.e., C does not contain a declaration of f or the
>   resulting declaration set is empty), S(f, C) is initially empty. If C
>   has base classes, calculate the lookup set for f in each direct base
>   class subobject B i , and merge each such lookup set S(f, B i ) in
>   turn into S(f, C).**

In your case, there is function `breathe` in class `fish`, compiler will not trying to found `breathe` in base class. You can resolve this by explicitly inserting `using` declaration in derived class.

```
using animal::breathe;
```

Now, compiler has two variant and due overloading resolution `animal::breathe` will be called.

Answer (score 0):

Google method hiding. Add

```
using animal::breathe;
```

To class fish

Answer (score 0):

```
fh.breathe();
```

is an error message, because there is another `breathe()` defined in the derived class, which effectively *hides* the `breathe()` defined in the base class.
You can correct this by adding the statement:

```
using animal::breathe;
```

in the class `fish`.

Modified `fish` class:

```
class fish: public animal {

    public:
        //Make sure to make this statement public
        //otherwise animal::breathe will not be accessible
        //to the object of fish.  
        using animal::breathe;
        void breathe(int a){
            cout << "fish bubble" << endl;
        }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

When you declare a function in derived class with same name as in base class, you are hiding the base class function. To bring base class function within derived class scope, you have to explicitly specify it using `using animal::breath` like so:

```
class fish: public animal {
public:
    using animal::breath;
    void breathe(int a){
        cout << "fish bubble" << endl;
    }
};
```